# How does this jpg file have transparency?

Tags: image, jpeg, transparent

My friend sent me a jpg over SMS and it seems to have a transparent background. I wonder what JPEG standard it's using that supports this. I checked the MIME type and it is a JPEG:
[image]
Its extension is .jpg. There's only a handful of things that can handle it. I can open it on my iPhone. I can't send it to anyone. I can't open it in Photoshop (I just says there's an error). Any help shedding a light on this will be very much appreciated!

The image is here (StackOverflow wouldn't even let me upload it):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPSAPbZ8-D28EUlEyBGs-CGqrzK4Aq0O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure it's a jpeg file and not something else (eg png) with a jpg extension?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a webp disguising as a jpg. False alarm everyone!
I figured it out using the "file" command in gitbash.
[image]